# SQL encode columns with yes/no values into a new column with codes according to another table

Tags: sql

I'm learning SQL and I'm trying to solve this problem, but I always get syntax errors and I don't know where to begin.

So I have this **cars** table:

| car | sedan | ABS | gasoline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prius | Y | Y | N |
| Camaro | N | N | Y |
| Mustang | N | Y | Y |

And this **feature_codes** table:

| Feature | Code |
| --- | --- |
| sedan | 1 |
| no sedan | 2 |
| abs | 3 |
| no abs | 4 |
| gasoline | 5 |
| no gasoline | 6 |

Then I want to modify the **cars** table so it looks like this:

| car | sedan | ABS | gasoline | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Prius | Y | Y | N | 1 |
| Prius | Y | Y | N | 3 |
| Prius | Y | Y | N | 6 |
| Camaro | N | N | Y | 2 |
| Camaro | N | N | Y | 4 |
| Camaro | N | N | Y | 5 |
| Mustang | N | Y | Y | 2 |
| Mustang | N | Y | Y | 3 |
| Mustang | N | Y | Y | 5 |

That is, I want to "encode" the columns with "yes" or "no" values, creating a new column with the codes according to the **feature_codes** table.

As an alternative, I'd like to create a new table with only the cars and the coded column (without the yes/no columns), like so:

| car | code |
| --- | --- |
| Prius | 1 |
| Prius | 3 |
| Prius | 6 |
| Camaro | 2 |
| Camaro | 4 |
| Camaro | 5 |
| Mustang | 2 |
| Mustang | 3 |
| Mustang | 5 |

I have tried to use JOIN with the CASE clause but I always get syntax errors.

Comment: So what is your *actual* question - why can't you accomplish it? Show your current attempt. We can't tell you what wrong with code or errors you are not including. I'd start by looking at your design, specifically how to normalise - having a column per attribute is not a good idea.

Comment: I have removed the <ansi-sql> tag, since the accepted answer isn't ANSI SQL compliant. (ANSI SQL has single quotes as string delimiters, and the double quotes are for identifiers.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I was trying to use the CASE clause, but that's not necessary.

For those with the same problem, here's my solution:

```
SELECT A.car, B.code FROM cars A
JOIN feature_codes B
ON (A.sedan = "Y" AND B.code = 1)
OR (A.sedan = "N" AND B.code = 2)
OR (A.abs = "Y" AND B.code = 3)
OR (A.abs = "N" AND B.code = 4)
OR (A.gasoline = "Y" AND B.code = 5)
OR (A.gasoline = "N" AND B.code = 6)
```

Then we can insert it into a new table.